# MemoryError while working with large files in Python

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory

So I'm trying to convert a few hundred 120MB-2GB sized .svs files (high-resolution microscopy photos at 40 times magnification) to jpeg tiles, and I keep getting MemoryError at the step where my script allocates large amounts of data to RAM. Do I simply need larger RAM or are there other tricks I can try?

My laptop has a 64-bit i3 processor and 4GB RAM (3.8 GB available, usually). I run Python 3.8.2. Even when I input only 1 of the smaller slides at once, this error occurs (see below), so I guess smaller batches are not possible. Downsampling will influence the scanning resolution, so that is not an option.

```
output_jpeg_tiles('D:/TCGA slides/TCGA-O1-A52J-01A.svs', 'D:/JPEG tiles')

converting D:/TCGA slides/TCGA-O1-A52J-01A.svs with width 66640 and height 25155

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    output_jpeg_tiles('D:/TCGA slides/TCGA-O1-A52J-01A.svs', 'D:/JPEG tiles')
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 22, in output_jpeg_tiles
    patch = img.read_region((begin_x, begin_y), 0, (patch_width, patch_height))
  File "C:\Users\...\site-packages\openslide\__init__.py", line 222, in read_region
    return lowlevel.read_region(self._osr, location[0], location[1],
  File "C:\Users\...\site-packages\openslide\lowlevel.py", line 258, in read_region
    buf = (w * h * c_uint32)()
MemoryError
```

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: It also depends on the way you have written output_jpeg_tiles and any other modules that you are using as part of this operation
you can use `print sys.getsizeof(variable)` to check which variable is consuming more amount of memory if you suspect some module's response

Comment: Are you using 32-bit python?

Comment: Fixed it! I was apparently using 32-bit python, which I never noticed because it did not cause any problems until now. I installed 64-bit python instead and am now in the process of (quite slowly) converting .svs images to jpeg one by one via a for-loop. Thank you for the quick response and the help!